# not understanding the constructed url in Django framework

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django framework and learning it; many time I get the url patterns in urls.py as given below

```
url(r'^tracking/(?P<some_slug>[\w.-]+)/(?P<mail_64>{})/$'.format(base64_pattern), 'tracking_image_url', name='tracking_image_url'),
```

I understand the part **P** but after that **[\w.-]+** is added or sometimes its simply w+.
Please can anyone make me understand these terms what they are? and for what they stand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` is a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) which matches any alphanumeric character and underscore.  So, `\w+` matches repeated alphanumeric characters (and underscores) and `[\w-]+` adds the `-` to the set of matchable characters.

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I have a little doubt about he answer that from where it takes the regular expression (from P<> or some other regex defined in urls.py)